# How to filter nested JSON children objects and return result Angular 8

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, angular8

I am getting API response inside `filterchildrenByRegion`() function,

I want to remove those object which are not matching with the selected Region and return all data as it is.

**Ex 1 -**
If i will pass `'1UL Africa'` inside changeRegion() function,than it will return data as my **expected output 1**.

**Ex - 2 -** If i will pass `'South Africa"'` inside changeRegion() function,than it will return data as my **expected output 2**.

```
changeRegion(){  
 this.newRegion = this.filterchildrenByRegion('1UL Africa');
}

 filterchildrenByRegion(region){      
   this.data = [
      {
        "name": "Africa",
        "children": [
          {
            "name": "Test1",
            "region": "1UL Africa"
          },
          {
            "name": "Test2",
            "region": "South Africa",
          },
          {
            "name": "Test3",
            "region": "New Test",
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        "name": "Europe",
        "children": [
          {
            "name": "Test4",
            "region": "1UL Africa"
          },
          {
            "name": "Test5",
            "region": "Test Europe"
          }
        ]
      }
    ];    
      return this.data.filter(x => x.children.map(child => child.region).includes(regionName));
  };
```

**Expected OutPut1**

```
 result =  this.data = [
      {
        "name": "Africa",
        "children": [
          {
            "name": "Test1",
            "region": "1UL Africa"
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        "name": "Europe",
        "children": [
          {
            "name": "Test4",
            "region": "1UL Africa"
          }
        ]
      }
    ];
```

**Expected OutPut 2**

```
 result =  this.data = [
      {
        "name": "Africa",
        "children": [
          {
            "name": "Test1",
            "region": "1UL Africa"
          }
        ]
      }     
    ];
```

Comment: Answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10865042/8941307)

Comment: @Pieterjan, Can you please add working solution on my code.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a sample that will work for your case

```js
return this.data.map((x) => {
        const childrenFulfillingTheSearch = x.children.filter(c => c.region.includes(region));

        if (childrenFulfillingTheSearch.length === 0) {
          return undefined; //this country has no children fulfilling the requirements
        }

        return {
          ...x,
          children: childrenFulfillingTheSearch
        };
      })
      .filter(x => x !== undefined);
```

[Click here to view a running example](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ssl=53&ssc=31&pln=40&pc=7#code/AQSwdgLgpgTgZgQwMZWASQEpQOYgPZjADewYCAtlAFzADOEM42ANMDDvmDfY2NsAF8AUENCRYiFOgDCeAK4MAnsVIVqdBk1ZIAFiAA2AE3ZdgAQRgwEigDyYOBAHzDgopPoS1awAMp5KPrAAbiBSRKLAhggQCDQWVrZosgowio7AALzAANoAugDconAG0DC6BsZQYABCili4BJnAABTsDaY8TACUcZbWdslK6RnpJMDj4xHAEHq0AHRRMU3ZUxPhExvAAERklFs0W2ZwjEgIW8yrG1vlRib7OZeb65svO2r3WwAqUPQAjOePV5tTgfX4AVQAMuZjqEzoCJgILi8Ns9kRM3nsDt96AAmAFoq7AggfPwKHTQk5nJEExHw8aogkYqAfbEQADM%20IJ4y2RLAHwAclAAO7AVmctEuZG5R60l4Mq67ZkHACichgeAADszqa8bpU%20TQVlz5cimSyfhAACzixm80GQimwrZ0wQ65Em16K830ACsNrRPIcBu2rOAqvVWudXMlL2lLxjwAKG0e7AgasIMxA80WCDm5AQGuazQAHl1MqN4UgCPRgHqTAAxOT6Yr6fRMT46KCBBBlclZYtzOtVOYt0rNJDl2tzXlzcDuOSGH6tINdLqFeEgOAtIdgRvNgxtvgdrtQHu6Ob6KrYGaZDJZAAMZY9E1T6eAcjAi%20KYCghnywAAegAzNvCrBQwFSYAdE8Ug8FrPRbiqYA4CbfdWyYNgoAARxAdhKEgeFhHhV8YEIZ9xjmSjizdF4dxoHc9xbQ9sGPbte0Iwp4y6R4RxKWAS0nYtgAAQjvd9Pygb9f24l48wLASRmAISYKSeQlDXCIBH-UQiKrMAa1oYJQlQLIfxFPwAiMlBmjXVw3GrCBpgtX4mkMmAQhQXj9FKHdanqThmi2cEoSOSktg02tqzwS8LzwbBmgAKR8AB5fk5k6PhN0UZpoD%20VcREi-THNyiAcVcqyoC8nyEP1Pyg0C0kb1Cp0IsK2hosq-Q4sSlK0oy3A4GykqcXy1wgA)

Comment: It is not returning any result..don't know why

Comment: Open the running example and click the *run* button. On the right side, you will see the console output and that it works the way you want with the input you provided. If it does not work, you have to provide a minimal not working sample so that someone can help you with that

Comment: What is the use of Icountry interface : .map(x => x as ICoutry);

Comment: To ensure the compiler that it will return ICountry. Otherwise, it will return an array of ICountry or undefined. It will be transpired to .map(x => x).
If that bothers you, we can change the approach like this:
```
return this.data.map((x) => {
        const childrenFulfillingTheSearch = x.children.filter(c => c.region.includes(region));
        return {
          ...x,
          children: childrenFulfillingTheSearch
        };
      })
      .filter(x => x.children.length > 0 );
```